# using components in anuglar-ui

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm making an angular 1 application with typescript and components. But my views arn't loaded.

and I can't seem to figure out why, the ui-router is working and my components are loading as wel if I include them in my index.html

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular typescript webpack</title>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <a ui-sref="app.home" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
    <a ui-sref="app.about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
    <messages-application></messages-application>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
import './modules/_application/index';
import './modules/about/index';

import 'angular';

angular.module('app', [ 'app.application', 'app.about']);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'], {
    strictDi: true
});
```

**modules/_application/index.ts**

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';

import {config as routesConfig} from './configs/routes';
import {MessagesApplicationComponent} from './components/messagesApplication/MessagesApplicationComponent';

angular.module('app.application', ['ui.router'])
    .component('messagesApplication', new MessagesApplicationComponent())
    .config(routesConfig);
```

**modules/_application/configs/routes.ts**

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
export function config($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider): void {
    let abstractState: ng.ui.IState = {
        abstract: true,
        name: 'app',
        component: 'messages-application'
    };


    $stateProvider.state(abstractState);
}
```

**modules/_application/components/messagesApplication/messagesApplicationComponent.ts**

```
export class MessagesApplicationComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    template: string = `
        <h1>Messages application</h1>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <h3>test</h3>`;
}
```

and then i have a route for my about

**modules/about/index.ts**

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import {PageAboutComponent} from './components/pageAbout/PageAboutComponent';
import {config as routesConfig} from './configs/routes';

angular.module('app.about', ['ui.router'])
    .component('pageAbout', new PageAboutComponent())
    .config(routesConfig);
```

**modules/about/configs/routes.ts**

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
export function config($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider): void {
    let aboutState: ng.ui.IState = {
        name: 'app.about',
        url: '/about',
        component: 'page-about',
        parent: 'app'
    };

    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
}
```

**modules/about/components/pageAbout/pageAboutComponent.ts**

```
export class PageAboutComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string = `
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Typescript</li>
            <li>Webpack</li>
            <li>Angular 1.4</li>
            <li>Karma</li>
            <li>Jasmine</li>
            <li>Istanbul coverage</li>
        </ul>
    </div>`;
}
```

anybody knows what I might be forgetting or doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting any errors? Anything that would suggest what's wrong?

Comment: @toskv nope no errors

Comment: how are you loading the js files?